# babel-loader failed to transpile vue-router to es5 code in mac

Tags: vue.js, babeljs, uglifyjs, gulp-uglify, babel-loader

babel-loader transpiles same code in windows successfully but can not turn vue-router in es5 in mac .

I rebuilt all the code without using vue-router and everything goes well. 
So i just wonder if there has anybody encountered this ?

mac: `10.12.4 (16E195)`

node: `v8.1.3`

package.json:

```
{
  "engines": {
    "node": "7.5.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.3.4",
    "vue-router": "^2.6.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.3.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.7.6",
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.1",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.2",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-component": "^0.9.1",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-assign": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.4.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.22.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.27.3",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^15.0.1",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.6.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.1.0",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "^0.10.1",
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "gulp-cssnano": "2.1.2",
    "gulp-delete-lines": "0.0.7",
    "gulp-eslint": "3.0.1",
    "gulp-less": "^3.3.0",
    "gulp-nodemon": "^2.2.1",
    "gulp-replace": "^0.5.4",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.8",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.3.11",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "less": "^2.7.2",
    "less-loader": "^4.0.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.3.3",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "run-sequence": "1.2.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "script-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.15.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "vue-loader": "^12.2.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.3.3",
    "webpack": "^2.6.1"
  }
}
```

.babelrc:

```
{
"presets": [
    ["es2015", { "modules": false }], "stage-1", "stage-2", "stage-3"
],
"plugins": [
    ["transform-vue-jsx"],
    ["transform-object-assign"],
    ["component", [{
        "libraryName": "element-ui",
        "styleLibraryName": "theme-default"
    }]]
]
```

}

webpack:

```
module.exports = {
entry: {
    app: `./client/app.js`
},
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, `../../`, config.destination),
    filename: `[name].js`
},
module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: `vue-loader`,
        options: {
            loaders: {
                js: 'babel-loader'
            }
        }
    }, {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: `babel-loader`,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/
    }],
    noParse: [/\/dist\/.+/]
},

resolve: {
    modules: [rootPath, `node_modules`],
    extensions: [`.js`, `.jsx`, `.vue`, `.json`, `less`, `scss`, `css`, `html`],
    alias: {
        vue: `node_modules/vue/dist/vue.js`,
        client: clientPath
    }
},

plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        mangle: false,
        comments: false,
        warnings: false,
        sourceMap: !!argv.test
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
        minimize: true
    })
],
devtool: `cheap-source-map`
```

};

Got error: `[ 'app.js from UglifyJs\nUnexpected token: keyword (default) [app.js:35217,7]' ]`
[image]

**Edition(2017-07-10 11:38:19)**

app.js: `import VueRouter from 'vue-router';`

`package.json` of `vue-router` in `node_modules` has this:

```
"main": "dist/vue-router.common.js",
"module": "dist/vue-router.esm.js",
"name": "vue-router",
```

So how to make babel use the `main` field rather than the `module` field ?

Comment: It looks like you are importing the `vue-router` src code directly, however, `babel-loader` is ignoring anything in `node_modules`. Make sure you are importing from `dist/vue-router.common.js` and not `src/index.js`

Comment: Why have you aliased `vue` like that? How are you importing `vue-router` in your code?

Comment: @craig_h Thanks for commenting. I just use `vue-router` like this `import VueRouter from 'vue-router';` and i saw the `package.json` of `vue-router` has this a `module` and a `main` field, so how specify the babel using the `main` field ?

Comment: @DecadeMoon Thanks for commenting, just see my above comments.

Comment: Why do you have uglify errors but you’re not using the uglify plugin in your webpack config?

Comment: @DecadeMoon I post the dev `webpack config` before, i have already edit the code to add minimal `webpack dist` config.